# How to do GLM where the response depends on the response of the same group?

Tags: r, regression, glm

I have a dataset

```
y x1 x2 x3
1 91 21 A1
0 54 87 A1
1 88 54 B1
1 67 42 B1
0 32 83 B1
.......
```

I first want to do a glm y~x1+x2 on the subset where x2>50 (I can do this with subsetting),

```
mdl1 <- glm(y~x1+x2, family=binomial, data=subset(df, x2>50))
```

then I want to do a second glm y~x1+x2+ y(from x2>50 and x3 is the same).

For example, the second line has x2=87 and x3=A1, then it's y=0 will have an effect on modeling the y for the first line which is in the same x3=A1, and has x2<50. Similarly, y from lines 3 and 5 will have an effect on line 4.

I don't know how to include this on the model.

```
mdl2 <- glm(y~x1+x2+???, family=binomial, data=subset(df, x2<=50))
```

I am suspecting y when x2<50 is dependent on other y's of the same x3.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Thomas, writing the model and code for the second glm.

Comment: Why don't you show the code you've already come up with in your question and then elaborate, since it's really not clear what you want.

Comment: @Thomas, I updated the post to include explanation, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could fit a combined glm that captures the idea that "y when x2<50 is dependent on other y's of the same x3":

```
mdl <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3:as.numeric(x2 < 50), family=binomial)
```

For x2 >= 50, `as.numeric(x2 < 50)` is zero, so the model is just y ~ x1 + x2. For x2 < 50,
`as.numeric(x2 < 50)` is one, so the model becomes y ~ x1 + x2 + x3.

with this approach the coefficients for x1 and x2 are based on all the data, but the effects of x3 are based only on the data with x2 < 50.